# Break the for loop while calling dev

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is as below:

```
def a(num):
    #if num == 2, then want to skip running b() and go on to next loop
    if a == 2:
      # i have tried break, pass and continue there
      # pass and continue return an error (SyntaxError: 'pass/continue' not properly in loop)

def b(num):
    print('b:' str(num))

for x in range(1,10):
    a(x)
    b(x)
```

How can I skip running `b()` when `num` is 2? I have tried `pass`, `continue` and `break` but no clue.

---

Thanks for your great help. I finally use `return` to make this possible. Thanks mate!

Comment: You are probably looking for `return`

Comment: Note that is your loop which always calls `a()`, then `b()`. It has nothing to do with which function definition appears first.

Answer (score 3):

```
  for x in range(1,10):
    a(x)
    if x != 2:
        b(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **continue** statement to skip the current iteration and continue with the next iteration unlike **break** statement (which terminates the loop).

Here is the code.

```
def a(num):
    print('a:', str(num))

def b(num):
    print('b:', str(num))

for x in range(1,10):
    if x == 2:
        continue
    a(x)
    b(x)
```

#### Output »

```
a: 1
b: 1
a: 3
b: 3
a: 4
b: 4
a: 5
b: 5
a: 6
b: 6
a: 7
b: 7
a: 8
b: 8
a: 9
b: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` or `continue` acts on the enclosing loop **in same scope**. That means that you cannot write the loop in a block calling functions and the break in a called function. The language does not allow it. Full stop.

You can either return a value from the function and test it, or raise an exception and catch it. Here is an example of exception usage:

```
class SkipException(Exception):
    pass

def a(num):
    if num == 2:
        raise SkipException

def b(num):
    print('b:', str(num))

for x in range(1, 10):
    try:
        a(x)
        b(x)
    except SkipException:
        pass
```

It gives as expected:

```
b: 1
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
```